# Password Salting/Hashing with bcrypt

Tags: algorithm, hash, passwords, bcrypt

So i've been trying to find a library to salt/hash my passwords using bcrypt algorithm but can't seem to find a well documented library. Any recommendations ?

Comment: You didn't mention a programming environment, what do you use?

Answer (score 1):

This is the standard implementation for C:

http://www.openwall.com/crypt/

PostgreSQL and many others use this open-source implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok noone seems to be interested. I'll try to share my own research results. OpenSSL/Botan/Crypto++/libsodium are the ones i came across. Had a chance to try Botan so far. It doesn't let you create a hash with your own salt but it has a function called bcrypt_check which gets the job done. Also it has bunch of other useful crypto/algorithm stuff.

Comment: You've also mentioned in your answer OpenSSL and Crypto++. Do they contain the algorithm for `bcrypt` or they contain an implementation for the `BlowFish` algorithm?