# What is the main C/C++ library for BCrypt?

Tags: encryption, openssl, cryptography, passwords, static-libraries

What is currently the main C/C++ library to use BCrypt?

Does OpenSSL really not support bcrypt? I haven't found anything for it in its crypto library.

Comment: Also see [What's the recommended Bcrypt C implementation?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9977256) and [Password Salting/Hashing with bcrypt](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31502473). Bcrypt is an early implementation of  [memory-hard functions](https://www.google.com/search?q=memory+hard+hash+function). Scrypt and a number of others are now available. Also see [Do any security experts recommend bcrypt for password storage?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/4781) on the Security Stack Exchange.

Comment: @jww Thanks. I've already seen those. I'll settle on openwall implementation if I manage to understand how to use it. Very surprising to see this information so nonexistent and outdated in general compared to everything else.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I found this C wrapper over the Openwall's implementation:
https://github.com/rg3/bcrypt

It's supposed to make it easier to use it.

Comment: Can I use this lib on windows?